# Por que mi componente no se renderiza(Vuejs)

Tags: html, vue.js

Mi componente debe renderizar una tabla con datos al presionar un botón, pero no aparece aunque la consola me muestra un `Array` con valores

```
Vue.component('list-din',{
  template:`<div>
  <b-button  @click="agrega">Agregar</b-button>
    <b-list-group v-if="render != undefined">
      <b-list-group-item v-for="(renglon, index) in this.renglones" v-bind:key="renglon.id"
      v-bind:title="renglon.opcion"
      v-on:remove="renglones.splice(index,1)" class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"><tinymce-estatico>{{renglon.opcion}}</tinymce-estatico>
      <b-badge variant="primary" pill>{{renglon.calificacion}}</b-badge>
      </b-list-group-item>
    </b-list-group>
  </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return{ renglones: [

    ],
    nextID : 0,
    render: false
  };
  },
  methods:{
    agrega(){
    Event.fire('trae-opcion');}
  },
  created:function(){
     if(typeof this.renglones == 'undefined'){
        this.renglones = new Array();
        this.nextID = 0;
        this.renglones.push({calificacion:1,opcion: opcion,id:this.nextID});
        render = true;
      }Event.listen('recive-opcion',function(opcion){
      console.log('chido');
         this.renglones.push({calificacion:1,opcion: opcion,id:this.nextID});
      console.log(this.renglones);
      this.nextID+=1;
    });
  } ,
});
```

Comment: Hola chubbyRick, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la información que falta según [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

**Primero**, donde pones

```
render = true;
```

debiera ser

```
this.render = true;
```

De lo contrario no estás cambiando la propiedad dentro de `data`.

**Segundo**, el bucle

```
if(typeof this.renglones == 'undefined'){
  ...
}
```

Nunca se cumple porque renglones está definido en duro como un array vacío.

**Tercero**, cuando escuchas el evento `recive-opcion` (debiera ser *recibe-opcion*) añades un elemento a `this.renglones` pero no cambias el valor de `this.render`. Debiera ser:

```
Event.listen('recive-opcion',function(opcion){
  this.renglones.push({calificacion:1,opcion: opcion,id:this.nextID});
  console.log(this.renglones);
  this.nextID+=1;
  this.render = true;
});
```

Sin embargo, **como sugerencia**, en realidad no necesitas modificar explícitamente la propiedad `render` sino que podrías declararla como una propiedad computed:

```
data() {
  return { 
    renglones: [],
    nextID : 0e
  };
},
computed: {
  render: function () {
    return this.renglones.length > 0;
  }
}
```

De manera que el valor de render cambie acorde a la cantidad de renglones.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ayudo a darme cuenta de mi verdaro error, mi componente nunca modifica el DOM luego de que se renderiza